# Can I travel on a domestic flight if my booking is not the same as my id?

Tags: bookings, domestic-travel, identity-cards

By mistake, I booked my flight using initials for my first and middle names. On my id, both names are written in full; the last name is the same. Can I travel on a domestic flight with this mistake?

Comment: Domestic flight where? They are usually more sticklers on the last name. I have several misspellings of my name however the last name was always consistent and always got away with it when noticed

Comment: @shyam A domestic flight where?

Comment: I had the same issue once and the information desk at the airport told me that you can have until three letters mistaken.

Comment: I think it all depends on the country and security.  In the US I would expect a hassle at the TSA checkpoint.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases the airlines will not have any problem with the difference, in other cases they will not accept it.

As soon as you notice the problem you should contact the airline you have bought the ticket for and ask them whether you need to do something and how to do so.

In some cases it is not the airline but the airport who might stop you from going to your plane, in that case having contacted the airline (and gotten a correction if needed) you can show the airport security officer that you have done what is needed. They should let you go on then but if you get any paperwork or an e-mail (or alike) answer, bring it.